# When using Selenium to control either ChromeDriver or GeckoDriver, I receive a JavaScript TypeError 'x' is not a function

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, typeerror

When using Selenium (via Java) to control either the ChromeDriver or the GeckoDriver I receive various JavaScript TypeError messages like `_.defaults is not a function`, `_.isArray is not a function`, `_.some is not a function`. It seems that the errors are raised for Lodash.js functions.

The error messages are only raised when using Selenium. I do not receive these error messages when using the native Chrome or Firefox browsers and the app operates normally with those browsers.

Because of these errors, the test execution stops when running with Selenium.

I am using Selenium version 4.12.1 and the latest versions of the ChromeDriver and GeckoDriver.

The [dev tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_development_tools) do not display any error messages.

Are there any Selenium settings that I could use to suppress the TypeError checking?